# iphone app with multiple AVAudioPlayer crashes on iOS 6 upon interruption

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, crash, avaudioplayer

I have an app that uses multiple AVAudioPlayer objects to play music. On iOS6, this app crashes when it is interrupted by a incoming phone call. The problem does not occur on iOS 4.3, 5.0 or 5.1. When the app crashes, the following stacktrace was seen.

(lldb) thread backtrace
* thread #1: tid = 0x2403, 0x3b905e64 libsystem_c.dylib`pthread_mutex_lock + 388, stop reason = instruction step over
    frame #0: 0x3b905e64 libsystem_c.dylib`pthread_mutex_lock + 388
    frame #1: 0x3299bd18 AVFoundation`AVAudioPlayerCpp::sessionPropertyListener(unsigned long, unsigned long, void const*) + 124
    frame #2: 0x33200b32 AudioToolbox`AudioSessionPropertyListeners::CallPropertyListenersImp(unsigned long, unsigned long, void const*) + 170
    frame #3: 0x332008cc AudioToolbox`AudioSessionPropertyListeners::CallPropertyListeners(unsigned long, unsigned long, void const*) + 244
    frame #4: 0x332b4afc AudioToolbox`ASCallbackReceiver_AudioSessionInterruptionListenerMessage + 184
    frame #5: 0x33389dde AudioToolbox`_XAudioSessionInterruptionListenerMessage + 70
    frame #6: 0x3320058a AudioToolbox`mshMIGPerform + 382
    frame #7: 0x337a33e6 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 34
    frame #8: 0x337a338a CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 138
    frame #9: 0x337a220e CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1382
    frame #10: 0x3371523c CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
    frame #11: 0x337150c8 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
    frame #12: 0x372f433a GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 74
    frame #13: 0x356312b8 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1120

I have added applicationWillResignActive and this does not get called when the crash occurs. I have also added my app delegate as a delegate to the AVAudioPlayer objects and implemented the audioPlayerBeginInterruption method. This method also does not get called when the crash occurs. If I use only 1 or 2 AVAudioPlayer objects, the crash goes away. The crash occurs with 3 more AVAudioPlayer objects, although only 2 of them are playing at a given time and the remaining have been stopped.

Has anyone seen this kind of problem or have any tips?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using delegate methods for handling the interruptions?  And have you looked through this documentation on handling the interruptions?  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/HandlingAudioInterruptions/HandlingAudioInterruptions.html

Comment: Yes, I am. Those delegate methods never get called when the crash occurs.